# Thunderbolt display on Macbook Pro Retina 11,1 (13'') w Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, macbook, thunderbolt

I've just successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux 3.13.0-30) on my Macbook pro retina (11,1) (this model has only an Intel GPU); following this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy

If I plug the external Thunderbolt display after the system is loaded, nothing happens; if I plug it before the boot, it was activated but the startup process requires up to 20 mins.

Also, after 5-10 minutes of usage, the system starts to run very slow 'til it completely stucks.

What I can do about this? 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It works when you install the drm-intel-next kernel from the mainline ppa. But I observe some fan issues then. see my last question.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to AU. Could you please provide more information on to how to install it. Also it's unclear to what other question you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm researching on the new fan issues as well.